# Badge details showing wrong value

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I earned the python badge 2 days ago, now I can't find it in my profile.
User name summary says I have 13 badges, but my badge list in my profile only shows 12.

Where is my missing badge? :'(

Comment: Your account on SO is not eligible for the python badge right now. Maybe one of your answers (or a question you answered) got deleted. Tag badges are removed if you no longer meet the requirements. But the badge counts do look wrong.

Comment: Not sure if you care, but your email is visible in the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag badges can be removed as well as awarded.

So if you fall below the threshold - 20+ answers with 100+ score - then the badge will be removed.

So if an answer was deleted (due to question migration or other deletion) or you received a down-vote or someone took away an up-vote you'd lose the badge. You can tell from the tags part of your profile what your score is and how many qualifying answers you've provided.

Once you hit the threshold again the badge will return.

As to why the numbers don't match - caching.